# Trying to wrap and underlying class just be inheritance, but cannot assign/cast value between them because of a protected constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, .net-6.0

In my LibraryA I reference a library ([MS Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview)) which has a classed called `User` ([src](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/model/User.cs))

I've made the "wrapper-class" `oUser` in LibraryA which inherit `Microsoft.Graph.User`:

```
    public class oUser : Microsoft.Graph.User
    {
    }
```

I now instantiate a `Microsoft.Graph.User` object and then try to assign it to a `oUser` object:

```
oUser _User = (oUser)user;
```

But I get this exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Graph.User' to type 'LibraryA.oUser'.
```

The `Microsoft.Graph.User` class inherit `Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObject` ([src](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/model/DirectoryObject.cs)) which inherit `Microsoft.Graph.Entity` ([src](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/model/Entity.cs)) which has this protected constructor:

```
public partial class Entity
{
   protected internal Entity()
      // Don't allow initialization of abstract entity types
   }

   [JsonPropertyName("id")]
   public string Id { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

I assume this is the reason, is there a workaround?

UPDATE:
Tried to create a new `oUser` object and assign a value to the `Id` property from `Entity` class which I could, so I assume this is not the problem afterall?

```
var _User = new oUser() { Id = "MyID" };
```

Comment: Why are you using inheritance here?

Comment: LibraryA is supposed to be a wrapper of `Microsoft.Graph` (among other). The idea is I only need to reference LibraryA and not Microsoft.Graph in the main application.

Comment: _"The idea is I only need to reference LibraryA and not Microsoft.Graph in the main application."_ - **That won't work**: your main app project will still need to reference the `Microsoft.Graph` library in order to use _any type_ from that lib, even if you're exposing your own derived type. (and why don't you want your main application project to reference an _actual dependency_? (even if it is transitive...).

Comment: Really just for simplicity. `Mirosoft.Graph` is a rather comprehensive library with a lot of dependencies. Which mean you really need to use nuget, which I think download 400MBs of packages (in case those dependencies are not already on your system). Just like the idea of only have to reference LibraryA dll (with the attached MS Graph dlls of course).

Answer (score 0):

> I assume this is the reason

No, it is not, since you *"instantiate a `Microsoft.Graph.User`"* it is not an instance of `oUser` so you can't [cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) `user` to it unless there is an [user-defined conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators).

> is there a workaround?

You have several options:

- instantiate `oUser` directly
- define an explicit user-defined conversion
- rework your approach by using composition over inheritance

Comment: I thought it was possible since they are identical (at least have the same properties). And I assume the last two options you mention will mean the values will be copied and not referenced, right?